# Which is faster: using django database order_by or list sort?

Tags: python, django, django-database

I have a Django model with `score` and `quizzes_done`. I want to calculate percentiles on both scores and quizzes_done. To do that, I need to create two sorted lists. For the first one, I do:

```
s_recs = MyRecord.objects.all().order_by('score')
score_list = [r.score for r in s_recs]
```

I can do the same to get a sorted `quiz_list` or I can use python sort. I am wondering which one is faster.

Use the `s_recs` we got above and do

```
quizzes_list = [r.quizzes_done for r in s_recs]
quizzes_list.sort()
```

OR

```
q_recs = MyRecord.objects.all().order_by('quizzes_done')
quizzes_list = [r.quizzes_done for r in q_recs]
```

Comment: try it and find out ... it probably depends on several factors ... I would guess for larger lists it will be faster to have sqlite or whatever ORDER BY

Comment: I bet the SQL solution is faster, and at the same you can offload the processing load to database too.

Comment: "It depends" is right. Python may well be faster for smaller datasets, but you generally want your database to do the ordering, as it "knows" what the data looks like, and may well already have an ordered (btree) index on the column you want to sort by, which will mean sorting results should run in `O(log N)` time rather than `O(N log N)` time. Another good question is, "does it matter?"

Comment: Yes somehow it sounds like premature optimization to me

Comment: I agree with Ben's comment. Also, if you need optimisation on retrieving thousands of objects, it might be worth to use a custom SQL with less information in the select. It depends what you want to achieve and how many scores you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried to test, and you folks are correct - for my dataset size, I do not see any significant difference. I will probably use the DB option, and hopefully, will reach a stage someday when I will need to optimize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little function that you can pass them both through to time:

```
def timedcall(fn, *args):
    "Call function with args; return the time in seconds and result."
    t0 = time.clock()
    result = fn(*args)
    t1 = time.clock()
    return t1-t0, result
```

This returns the timing and any result returned by the function you call. I think you will find that unless you are sorting upwards of 10s of thousands of records there will be little difference, but I would be interested to hear the results.